# R automaticly changes dates' format

Tags: r

My R changes format of dates to character or numeric.

```
For Example this code:
x <- as.Date("2018-06-20")
cat(x)
```

will print `"2018-06-20"`

but This code:

```
x <- as.Date("2018-06-20")
foo <- function(x) {
  cat(x)
}
foo(x)
```

will print a number `18433` and sometimes `"2018-06-20"` as character.

Hot to fix it?

Comment: It is printing both cases as numbers for me.  Dates are stored as numeric form.  anyway, you can try `cat(as.character(x))#
2018-06-20` or use `print(x)#[1] "2018-06-20"`

Comment: but in my colleauge R everything works fine

Comment: may be it is stored as character for your colleague.  Please check the `str`

Comment: no, we run the same code and in my R, R convert all dates into characcters and his R, R treats dates as dates.

Comment: If you are doing some debugging, why don't you use `print` inside the function.   As I mentioned, please check the `str` of both cases to see if they are `Date` class or just `class(x)`

Answer (score 3):

According to `?cat`

> ```
> Currently only atomic vectors and names are handled, together with
>  ‘NULL’ and other zero-length objects.  
>   Other types of R object should be converted (e.g., by
>      ‘as.character’ or ‘format’) before being passed to ‘cat’.  That
>      includes factors, which are output as integer vectors.
> ```

`Date` objects are stored as `numeric`

```
typeof(x)
#[1] "double"
```

So, it is doing the coercion to numeric with `cat`.  One option is to convert to `character` (as mentioned in the documentation) and it should work

```
cat(as.character(x))
#2018-06-20
```

Comment: I've got something like this: `x = as.Date("2018-06-20"); foo <- function(x) { cat(class(x)); foo2(x)} ; foo2 <- function(x) { cat(class(x))} ;`  in the first foo i get Date but in the second I got NA

Comment: @stakowerflol  Yes, class is `Date`, but the storage mode is numeric.  You can check by `as.numeric(x)#
[1] 17702`